# Self-join with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-order-by, hibernate-criteria

Can't figure out a way to add order by for a Criteria on this kind of pseudo search index table:

```
----------------------------------
| id | person_id | field | value |
----------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | fname  | John |
| 2  | 1         | lname  | Smith|
| 3  | 1         | zip    | 3000 |
| 4  | 2         | fname  | John |
| 5  | 2         | lname  | Doe  |
| 6  | 2         | zip    | 3000 |
----------------------------------
```

The search_index table is an index for person entity, which can have any number of any kind of attributes (this is a simplified example of a real life problem of course). One "person" can have fname set, another may not and so on. Then a client app sends a generic search request, f.i. ((fname=John OR fname=Karl) AND lname=Smith and zip=3000) - this kind of stuff. So the system is fairly generic - list of searchable fields in search_index and any kind of boolean search query. Same goes for orderby - can be any of this searchable fields.

In SQL I would do something like:

```
SELECT si1.person_id from search_index si1
LEFT OUTER JOIN search_index si2 ON si1.id = si2.id
WHERE si2.field='lname'
AND si1.person_id in (select person_id from search_index where field = 'zip' and answer = '3000')
ORDER BY si2.value
```

to order found results by "lname".

It's probably possible with HQL but the search criterias are built dynamically from a search string and Hibernate Criteria API makes it a lot easier compare to dynamic HQL construction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you LEFT JOIN the same table and then you use the the JOINED table in a WHERE clause? This would be equivalent to an INNER JOIN.
2. Why do have an additional sub-select when you already joined the two tables.
3. Why do you even JOIN the two tables by their ID anyway? In this query of yours, you join identical rows (because you use the table ID as a join criteria).

Could this query be what you were looking for?

```
SELECT si1.person_id 
from search_index si1
LEFT OUTER JOIN search_index si2 ON si1.person_id = si2.person_id AND si2.field='lname' 
WHERE si1.field = 'zip' and si1.answer = '3000'
ORDER BY si2.value
```

The HQL and Criteria queries can only help you when navigating existing associations (which is not the case for the self join). So you should use a native query in this case.

Now, back to your query. You can remove the JOIN and write it like:

```
SELECT si1.person_id 
from search_index si1
WHERE si1.field='lname'
AND si1.person_id in (select person_id from search_index where field = 'zip' and answer = '3000')
ORDER BY si1.value
```

In this case, you can write an HQL query:

```
select p.id
from SearchIndex si
join si.person p
where 
   si.field = :field1 and
   p.id in (select si2.person.id from SearchIndex si2 where si2.field = : field2 and answer = :answer)
order by si.value
```

### Update

If the 'lname' field is only useful for ordering, then you need to move the sub-query into your main query and move the 'lname' in a join instead:

```
SELECT si1.person_id 
from search_index si1
where si1.field = 'zip' and si1.answer = '3000'
LEFT OUTER JOIN search_index si2 ON si1.person_id = si2.person_id AND si2.field='lname' 
ORDER BY si2.value
```

This needs a native query, because of the self-join syntax.

Comment: 1. Good point. I was trying to get around the fact that there maybe no row in the index table. But you are right, my example doesn't deal with that very well anyway.

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know which option do you really want. I gave you an HQL query solution too.

Comment: 2. That's an example of a search "zip=3000 order by lname". There can be a search for "zip = 3000 AND fname=John order by lname". There comes the need for subqueries
3. No sure how else to do that. I need to find rows that satisfy the search criteria and then apply orderBy on top of that

Comment: Your second option is something I have been playing around myself in the past hour. That's probably doable. I'll come back to you a bit later if it worked out. The disadvantage that there has to be a orderby row for every person_id, which is not necessarily true. There can be person_id = 3 in that table without lname.

Comment: So then the lname is used only for ordering, and not for filtering? So you want to get all persons with the zip and 3000, but ordered by lname if there's a match?

Comment: The search_index table is an index for person entity, which can have any number of any kind of attributes (this is a simplified example of a real life problem of course). One "person" can have fname set, another may not and so on. Then a client app sends a generic search request, f.i. ((fname=John OR fname=Karl) AND lname=Smith and zip=3000) - this kind of stuff. So the system is fairly generic - list of searchable fields in search_index and any kind of boolean search query. Same goes for orderby - can be any of this searchable fields. Sorry for the confusion.